# .NET MVC Contact Form Fails to Send Email on Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email

I am using .NET MVC to send a contact form to my work email.  The code runs with no errors, but the email never arrives.  It works on my local server when using a gmail account, but fails on my server when trying to use my work email.  To temporarily fix this issue, I have successfully added .aspx version of the contact form and it works fine.  Any ideas why MVC in particular doesn't work on the server?  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Eclipse.Models;
using System.Net.Mail;


namespace Eclipse.Controllers
{
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {

      private void SendEmail(string subjectText, string bodyText)
      {
         MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

         message.To.Add("info@emaildomain.com");
         message.From       = new MailAddress("noreply@emaildomain.com",
                                              "My Company Inc.");
         message.Subject    = subjectText;
         message.Body       = bodyText;
         message.IsBodyHtml = false;

         SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.emaildomain.com");

         client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
         client.Port           = 25;
         client.EnableSsl      = false;
         client.Credentials    = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("noreply@emaildomain.com",
                                                                  "password");

         client.Send(message);
         client.Dispose();
      }

      [Route("~/Contact")]
      public ActionResult Contact()
      {
         if (TempData["FormMessage"] != null)
         {
            ViewBag.Message = TempData["FormMessage"].ToString();
            TempData.Remove("FormMessage");
         }

         return View();
      }

      [Route("~/ResultQuestion")]
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult ResultQuestion(ResultContact form)
      {
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
            try
            {
               System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

               builder.Append("Contact Information\n");
               builder.AppendFormat("Contact Name: {0}\n", form.Name);
               builder.AppendFormat("Contact Email: {0}\n", form.Email);
               builder.AppendFormat("Contact Phone: {0}\n", form.Phone);
               builder.AppendFormat("Gender: {0}\n", form.Gender);
               builder.AppendFormat("Age: {0}\n", form.Age);
               builder.AppendFormat("Event: {0}\n", form.Event);
               builder.AppendFormat("Bib: {0}\n", form.Bib);

               builder.Append("\nQuestions\n");
               builder.Append(form.Question);

               SendEmail("Result Question from web site", builder.ToString());

               ModelState.Clear();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
               ModelState.Clear();
               TempData["FormMessage"] = string.Format("We're sorry but an error occurred while submitting your request! {0}",
                                           error.Message);
            }
         }
         TempData["FormMessage"] = "Thank you for contacting us.  We will be in contact with you soon.";
         return RedirectToAction("Contact");
      }

      [Route("~/EventInquiry")]
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult EventInquiry(EventContact form)
      {
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
            try
            {
               System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

               builder.Append("Contact Information\n");
               builder.AppendFormat("Contact Name: {0}\n", form.Name);
               builder.AppendFormat("Contact Email: {0}\n", form.Email);
               builder.AppendFormat("Contact Phone: {0}\n", form.Phone);

               builder.Append("\nEvent Information\n");
               builder.AppendFormat("Event Name: {0}\n", form.Event);
               builder.AppendFormat("Event Date: {0}\n", form.Date);
               builder.AppendFormat("Location: {0}, {1}\n", form.City, form.State);
               builder.AppendFormat("Sport: {0}\n", form.Sport);
               builder.AppendFormat("Expected Participants: {0}\n", form.Participants);

               builder.Append("\nComments\n");
               builder.Append(form.Comments);

               SendEmail("Event Inquiry from web site", builder.ToString());

               ModelState.Clear();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
               ModelState.Clear();
               TempData["FormMessage"] = string.Format("We're sorry but an error occurred while submitting your request! {0}",
                                           error.Message);
            }
         }

         TempData["FormMessage"] = "Thank you for contacting us.  We will be in contact with you soon.";
         return RedirectToAction("Contact");
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely your email server is blocking the access.  To make it work with gmail you had to change a setting in gmail to allow applications to send on behalf of the account.  I think you'll need to do something similar with your email server but without more information it's hard to say.

Comment: But why does it work with an .aspx file?  It's basically the same code in MVC.

Comment: Oh, I missed that in your question.  Can you post the code that's trying to send the email from the MVC controller action?